# How to read lines of a streaming api with aiohttp in Python?

Tags: python, streaming, aiohttp

I am trying to convert a Python HTTP client featuring `requests` to `aiohttp`. The logic is to send a GET call to a REST endpoint which streams data occasionally and print the lines it returns.

I have a code using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) with `stream=True` option and `iter_lines`, it works pretty fine:

```
import json
import requests

def main():
    with requests.get('https://my-streaming-url.com', stream=True) as r:
        if r.encoding is None:
            r.encoding = 'utf-8'
        for line in r.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
            if line:
                # Print each line emitted by the streaming api
                print(json.loads(line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, I want to convert this logic to [aiohttp streaming api](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/streams.html#asynchronous-iteration-support) and tried:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def main():
    r = aiohttp.request('get', 'https://my-streaming-url.com')
    async for line in r.content:
        print(json.loads(line))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop.run_until_complete(connect_and_listen())
    loop.close()
```

I get an error like:

> ... in connect_and_listen
>
> async for line in r.content:
>
> AttributeError: '_SessionRequestContextManager' object has no attribute 'content'
>
> sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession._request' was never awaited
>
> Unclosed client session
>
> client_session: aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fac6ec24310

I tried a few ways like removing `loop.close()` from `main`, removing `async` from the `for` loop, but none helped.

What am I missing here? How can I print a streaming api lines with `aiohttp`?

P.S: My Python version is 3.7.5

Answer (score 7):

As throughout the documentation usage of [`ClientSession`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#client-session) class is encouraged, I had this code also encapsulated a session like follows and it worked:

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as session:
        async with session.get(cashcog_stream_url) as r:
            async for line in r.content:
```

Another point is `loop.close()` is apparently does not affect the way app works and can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Your missing the await keyword.</s>
`aiohttp.request` is an async context manager. you should use it with an async with statement

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.request('get', 'http://localhost:5000') as r:
        async for line in r.content:
            print(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: It throws `TypeError: object _SessionRequestContextManager can't be used in 'await' expression`